# .NET: Connecting to MySQL issues

Tags: .net, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a .NET app which uses a MySQL database.

The problem is that if I want to run it, the local computer requires the MySQL Connector to be installed.

How could I make this easier ? 
Can I "embed" everything and provide in one pack with my app ? 
Should I create an installer that does install the connector if missing and automatically creates the data source ?

Which is the best way to go ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think MySql connector comes with a DLL which just needs to be copied in youir BIN folder to let it go.

Just add the DLL with Setup project and it will copy the DLL while installing your app.

Comment: Please write all the names of the file with your question and I will pick one. I can't recall that way but if I'll see I can.